# Order with nested describe

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm using mocha-steps to build test sequens. In my case i have, let's call them "main", test and several sub-tests for each of them. Looks like:

1. Test 1

   - sub-test
   - sub-test
2. Test 2

   - sub-test
   - sub-test

```
step("Test 1", () => {})
describe("Sub-test 1", () => {
  it("Sub-Test 1", () => {})
  it("Sub-Test 1", () => {})
})
step("Test 2", () => {})
describe("Sub-test 2", () => {
  it("Sub-Test 2", () => {})
  it("Sub-Test 2", () => {})
})
```

So i expect them to run as written, but actually its:

```sh
✓ Test 1
✓ Test 2
  Sub-test 1
    ✓ Sub-Test 1
    ✓ Sub-Test 1
  Sub-test 2
     ✓ Sub-Test 2
     ✓ Sub-Test 2
```

In this case if "Test 2" fails, Sub-test won't run at all, but i need "Sub-test 1" to be completed because they depends only on "Test 1" and not "Test 2"

I tried to separate all test in different "describes", but then "step" does not work at all

## My Solution:

I found that default way mocha execute describe is:

- other code
- it
- describe

This behavior defined in mocha/lib/runner.js
So i found nothing else then redefine runner (and Suite) myself after `mocha` is required

I still want to find solution without changing mocha's code.
If someone interested in, i can paste code on gist for example.

Answer (score 0):

Nest them and set a flag when step 1 is successful, then assert on that flag in step 2:

```
const assert = require('assert');

let step1Success = false;
describe('Test 1', function () {
  step('Test 1', function () { 
    // ... Test 1 code
    step1Success = true;
  })
  describe('Sub-test 1', function () {
    it('Sub-Test 1', function () { })
    it('Sub-Test 1', function () { })
  })
})
describe('Test 2', function () {
  step('Test 2', function () {
    assert.ok(step1Success);
    // ... Test 2 code
  })
  describe('Sub-test 2', function () {
    it('Sub-Test 2', function () { })
    it('Sub-Test 2', function () { })
  })
})
```

---

**Details**

["Any failing `step` will abort the parent `describe` immediately"](https://github.com/rprieto/mocha-steps#mocha-steps) so a failure in either `step` will abort its parent `describe` and not run the associated sub-tests.

In addition, if `'Test 1'` does not complete then the flag will not be set and `step 2` will fail immediately.

(Normal functions used since ["passing arrow functions (aka "lambdas") to Mocha is discouraged"](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions))

Comment: this won't work, i tried alredy, as far as `steps` are in different `describes` they do not affect each other

Comment: Main problem is that i want to "Test 2" to depend on "Test 1" result, and so sub-tests